# Reading data from postgresql database into R without converting columns into factors

Tags: r, postgresql

Facing the below listed problems while reading data from postgresql database into R using '**dbReadTable**', '**postgresqlReadTable**' functions from 'RPostgreSQL' library.

1. R reads the NULL values from the database as "//N"
2. Columns are read as factors
3. Spaces,special characters between the column names are replaced as "."

Are there any options similar to ***as.is***, ***na.strings***, ***check.names*** in '**dbReadTable**' /  '**postgresqlReadTable**'?

Comment: 1) I cannot replicate.  2) You can override via `options("stringsAsFactors"=FALSE)`.  3)  That is standard R constraint on names of columns in data.frames as they could be come variables.  You can override after the fact using backtick escapes.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Both 'dbReadTable' & 'postgresqlReadTable' are functions in 'RPostgres package'. I have tried both the functions and none of them served my purpose

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel How to use "stringAsFactors=FALSE" option in 'dbReadTable' / 'postgresqlReadTable'? I couldn't find any such option in both the functions?

Comment: Now you are imprecise. There is a (CRAN) package [RPostgreSQL](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RPostgreSQL) -- which your question refers and which my answer addresses -- and another (GH only) package [RPostgres](https://github.com/rstats-db/RPostgres).  Which one do your comments talk about?  In short, there is a reason we all prefer _reproducible examples_ in questions.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was talking about 'RPostgreSQL' package which contains 'dbReadTable' & 'postgresqlReadTable' packages.

Comment: Look at the included examples and test scripts.  I prefer functions `dbGetQuery()` and friends.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Even dbGetuery() reads the data in the same way. Doesn't provide any options for reading data. Also, tried options("stringsAsFactors"=FALSE) it solved 2. But, couldn't solve 1 & 3

Comment: You are wasting your time, and the time of your readers.  Construct a reproducible example by writing a data.frame to a table, then query from it.  Demonstrate that the column is a factor.  Below I have a counter-example.  I have nothing more to add until you solidy your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counter-example retrieving *character* rather than factor:

```
 R> res <- dbGetQuery(con, 
 +       "select distinct symbol from stockinfo where symbol like 'SCH%'")     
 R> res 
    symbol      
 1    SCHG     
 2    SCHE 
 3    SCHV 
 4    SCHP 
 5    SCHB 
 6    SCHH
 7    SCHD 
 8    SCHZ
 9    SCHC 
 10   SCHO 
 11   SCHF 
 12   SCHR  
 13   SCHM
 14   SCHX 
 15   SCHA 
 R> class(res[,1])     
 [1] "character"
 R>
```